# conditional Operator ? : type evaluation

Tags: java, conditional-statements

```
void method(Set<String> whiteListProviders){

        HashSet<String> hashedWhitelistedProviders;

        HashSet<String> fdsfh = (hashedWhitelistedProviders = (HashSet<String>) whitelistedProviders);

        HashSet<String> ghjk = (hashedWhitelistedProviders = new HashSet<String>(whitelistedProviders));

        HashSet<String> gh4jk = true ? fdsfh : ghjk; //compiles

        true?fdsfh:ghjk; //gives error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashSet<String> to boolean" 




}
```

I read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25 
but still couldn't understand why it is giving compilation error in eclipse

Comment: I don't think that's even a valid statement in isolation.

Comment: Holy variable names, Batman!

Comment: tricky but interesting question to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java only allows assignments and calls where a statement is expected, not arbitrary expressions.

From section [14.8 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8):

> Certain kinds of expressions may be used as statements by following them with semicolons:
>
> ```
> ExpressionStatement:
>         StatementExpression ;
>
> StatementExpression:
>         Assignment
>         PreIncrementExpression
>         PreDecrementExpression
>         PostIncrementExpression
>         PostDecrementExpression
>         MethodInvocation
>         ClassInstanceCreationExpression
> ```

The ternary operator (`ConditionalExpression`) is not on that list, so it can't appear except as part of a larger expression or initializer.